# Add variable number of vectors to matrix

Tags: r, variables, for-loop, vector, cbind

I am trying to write a function that adds a variable number of vectors to a matrix.

This is how I get the vectors x1 - xi

```
for (i in 2:ncol(datasource))
{
   temp1 <- paste("x", i-1, sep = "")
   assign(temp1, as.numeric(unlist(datasource[i])))
 }
```

from datasources with varying numbers of columns. So what I want to do is:

```
df <- data.frame()
for (i in 2:ncol(datasource))
  {
    df <- cbind(paste("x", i-1, sep = ""))
  }
```

for the number of x1-xi vectors there are. But this doesn't work since the output of paste() is of mode "character". Is there a function which can bind vectors together one by one in a for loop?

The output I'd wish to get:

```
df
     x1    x2
[1,]  3 21.50
[2,]  3 43.00
[3,]  2 19.90
[4,]  4 36.00
[5,]  4 44.00
[6,]  6 49.80
[7,]  0  1.30
[8,]  0  0.67
[9,]  2 13.40
```

Thank you all very much in advance!

Comment: please post a reproducible example along with expected output

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
mtx <- matrix( x1, ncol=1 )
for (i in 2:ncol(datasource))
  {
    mtx <- cbind( get( paste0("x", i-1), mtx))
  }
```

And then convert to data.frame. The `cbind.data.frame` function cannot handle an empty dataframe as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks! With get() I now get the variable name instead of a character string. But now unfortunately cbind() needs all the vectors at once and doesn't work in a loop that way as far as I undestand.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the help of 42- I got it:

```
mtx1 <- matrix(NA, ncol=ncol(datasource)-1, nrow=nrow(datasource))

for (i in 2:ncol(datasource))
{
  mtx1[,i-1] <- get(paste0("x", i-1)) 
}

df1 <- as.data.frame(mtx1)
```